# Nifi, processor group. How to map all allowed path to just one listening port of different headers

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

Lemme come straight into this.
Well, I have implemented Nifi to localhost. It's working well and everything seems to be perfect.

I have made many different flows with headers of course within the cluster as below.
[Cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HywLH.png)

When I right click the header and go to "View configuration" go to "Properties" will see as follows.

[Processor details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZUlK.png)

You can see the "Listening Port" that is 10004 and a "hostname" as well. Then there is "Allowed path" as can be seen. 
Now If I want to access this specific header I have to hit using 10.0.0.18:10004/spec/transform.

Now the issue is, I have many different headers which are having a different listening port that is assigned by me. NIFI is not allowing me to assign the same port for every flow I make. but I have to assign different port every time I make a new flow. I just want to assign port 10004 to every other flow and just differ them using the "Allowed path".

How come I make this possible. I have to always assign new port to every new flow. Is there a way to do that. Hope you guys understand what am I actually willing to have. Hope to have your answers soon.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can have one HandleHttpRequest at the beginning of your flow listening on port 10004, and set the "Allowed Paths" property to a regular expression that matches all of the paths you want to support. HandleHttpRequest will add the path as an attribute to each flow file named "http.context.path", so you could then use a RouteOnAttribute to route each path to a different part of the flow.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Ill tried doing as you said but still its not working and it throws an exception. I might be missing something. Can you elaborate a lil more considering im a noob :P. Thank you so much again really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As Bryan Bende
but in nifi 1.14.0 that is attribute: http.request.uri